# SF novel inspired by Moby Dick and featuring "Sand Skiffs"

Tags: story-identification

A friend asked me for help identifying a science fiction novel. Notably he was not allowed to check the book out as it was in the adult section of the library and he only had a children's card so in actual fact he never read it. What he remembers is based very loosely on the blurb on the back of the book. This does not leave much to go on but fingers crossed...

- It was in his local library when he was a child in the early 80's so likely published between 1960 and 1980.
- He remembers a bluish cover but is vague on what it might have depicted.
- Very specifically he remembers being told by the librarian and/or read on the book cover that the book was an sf retelling of Moby Dick.
- He tells me he is certain the blurb talked about "sand skiffs" and that the setting was desert rather than ocean.

These last two points immediately made me think of *Involution Ocean* by Bruce Sterling (actually I have never read it but just by hearsay it's a very close match). This novel features a desert like environment, is clearly a riff on on *Moby Dick* and features craft called "dust whalers". My friend is sticking to his guns and saying the term was "sand skiffs" despite me pointing out that he is likely confusing the skiffs from *Return of the Jedi* with the dust whalers.

So, on the off chance that he is right and I am wrong, can anyone on this site ID an SF novel inspired by *Moby Dick* and specifically featuring craft referred to as "Sand Skiffs".

Not sure if there is any way to prove that no such novel exists or phrase a question in that manner that would be acceptable on this site but, If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate if you could leave them in the comments.

Comment: Red Dust by Paul McCauley has a desert environment and 'Dust Whalers'. It's nothing to do with Moby Dick though...

Comment: Michael Moorcock's *The Ice Schooner* (1969) has ice whaling boats hunting ice whales and has a very Moby Dick vibe. The different covers tend to be bluish because of the ice. Is it possible your friend mistakes ice for sand? Sand isn't exactly blue... https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60157.The_Ice_Schooner

Comment: Doesn't Paul Altriedes spend half of Volume 17 of Dune chasing the Great White Sandworm?

Comment: The Wind Whales of Ishmael? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjA7ujI156FAxWeW0EAHVboAMcQFnoECCoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F435294.The_Wind_Whales_of_Ishmael&usg=AOvVaw17Osuema16v-CAYN1dkdSk&opi=89978449

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is *[Involution Ocean](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Moby-Dick)* by Bruce Sterling.

The novel is a scifi retelling of Moby Dick set on a desert planet.

> The novel Involution Ocean by Bruce Sterling, published in 1977, features the world Nullaqua where all the atmosphere is contained in a single, miles-deep crater. The story concerns a ship sailing on the ocean of dust at the bottom, which hunts creatures called dustwhales that live beneath the surface. It is a science-fictional pastiche of Moby-Dick.

It specifically features "dustwhalers" and mentions a "dust skiff":

> *Here’s greasy luck,” said Calothrick cheerfully, giving the dustwhaler’s traditional toast His voice sounded unnaturally loud. Unconsciously I gripped the seat of my stool.*

And:

> *We did not land but exchanged greetings with several merchant vessels and a shrimp boat. I bought a new jackknife from an old man in a trading skiff.*

Blue covers.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Wind Whales of Ishmael by Philip Jose Farmer has the titular protagonist transported to the far future, where flying whales are hunted; but by air-ships, not sand skiffs.

Comment: @Valorum great find with the quote about the skiff. I really want to accept this as an answer, I am 99% convinced Involution Ocean is the one but my friend still isn't sure... what to do...?

Comment: @skyjack - I've added an image of the rear cover. If all he saw was that and the front, it may be worth showing him those images.

Comment: @Valorum many many thanks! I wish I had thought to hunt for this. My friend remembers the name Lunglance so we can finally tick this off and mark it correct! I seriously owe you beer for this! Thank you!

Comment: @skyjack - [Always a pleasure](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)